# Mysql 8.0 "ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 100" when adding index to very large table

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mysql-8.0

I'm attempting to add an index to a very large table (2B rows) and the command fails after a few hours with:

> ERROR 1030 (HY000): Got error 100 - 'InnoDB error' from storage engine

I'm finding the InnoDB `100` error code to be ungoogleable. It seems to be running out of some kind of resource, but the server has 128 GB of RAM and tons of disk space. Mysql isn't crashing.

I think maybe I need some config tweaks to give it more juice, but I don't know where to start.

Server version: Server version: 8.0.28
Db engine: InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the setting for `tmpdir` is pointing into a small disk partition.  Check

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

Comment: This was indeed the cause. The root partition filled up to 100% because of temp tables in /tmp. Then the query failed and the disk usage got freed. Moving the tmpdir to a larger partition has solved it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating an index inside of a virtual machine and it ended up filling up the entire virtual disk and close to the entire partition on the host. After migrating to a larger drive, the solution to avoiding `InnoDB error`, `table full`, or `Temporary file write failure` errors was expanding the virtual disk.